# pytorch language table for use in deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, translation, pytorch, vocabulary

can anyone tell me the error here?

```
import pytorch_translator as pt
import pickle
import torch
# Set up the dictionary (vocab table)
pairs, src, tgt = pt.genLangs("de", "en", "train-short.txt", vocab_size=6000)
with open("langs.pkl", 'wb') as outfile:
     pickle.dump((src, tgt), outfile)

teacher_forcing_ratio = 0.5
hidden_size = 128
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 # Set up the dictionary (vocab table)
>   ----> 2 pairs, src, tgt = pt.genLangs("de", "en", "train-short.txt", vocab_size=6000)
>         3 with open("genLangs.pkl", 'wb') as outfile:
>         4     pickle.dump((src, tgt), outfile)
>         5
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'genLangs'

There is something wrong with the genLangs but i can't find anything about this in pytorch, which suggests that it is wrong, but i don't know what is right to go there. completely removing it gives a syntax error.

Comment: How you import pytorch_translator? Is this written by yourself?

Comment: It's not written by me, but i'm meant to use it. The part with the imports shows no problems.

Comment: What is `pytorch_translator`. This is not an official package from `pytorch`. Maybe, you would like to post the source of `pytorch_translator` and explain what it is?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions, this was a fault with another file, and has been solved.